# WPF and ViewModel Property Access

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, viewmodel

My application's main component is a tab control which holds N number of views and those views' datacontext is a separate ViewModel object. I have a statusbar at the bottom of the app and it contains a few textboxes. I want one of the textboxes to reflect a timestamp for the currently selected tab. The timestamp is a property of the ViewModel object that's set as the view's datacontext.

I'm a WPF newb and not really sure how to bind that property to the status bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

For example...

```
/// <summary>
/// Sample ViewModel.
/// </summary>
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Timestamp property
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Timestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Timestamp;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._Timestamp)
            {
                this._Timestamp = value;

                // NOTE: This is where the ProperyChanged event will get raised
                //       which will result in the UI automatically refreshing itself.
                OnPropertyChanged("Timestamp");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Event
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise the PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region Private Fields

    private DateTime _Timestamp;

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=tabControl, Path=SelectedItem.DataContext.Timestamp}" />
```

A little depending on if your tabcontrol's itemssource is databound or not.

Comment: Using SelectedContent.DataContext.Timestamp worked somewhat. It doesn't update unless I select another tab and then select that tab again. What could I do to update the textblock when that property changes?

Comment: Do all your ViewModels implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Chris, no they don't. I wasn't aware of that interface, I'm new to WPF :) Looks like I have some more reading to do.

Comment: If your ViewModels implement INotifyPropertyChanged, then whenever the Timestamp property changes in your ViewModel the PropertyChanged event will be raised. WPF will recognize the PropertyChanged event and automatically update the UI for you.

Comment: @Chris, could you post an answer with the example implemented methods implemented to raise an event for my Timestamp property?